# React 403 Forbidden Error from a Express Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

**Error:** * http://localhost:5004/api/auth/login 403 (Forbidden) in the console log, I have Installed cors on the express but still on the console claims 403 Error*

Here I get my inputs and try to do a post request using AXIOS library.
***React***

```
      const click = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("Email:", email);
    console.log("Password:", password);
    console.log("Password:", checkMeOut);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5004/api/auth/login", {
        email:  email ,
        password:  password ,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setcheckMeOut("");
  };
```

***Express***

*App.js*

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const cors = require("cors");
const { sequelize, User } = require("./models");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors()); // Use this after the variable declaration
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
```

*route*

```
    router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: { email },
    });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(403).json("User Does not Exists");
    }
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!validPassword) {
      return res.status(403).json("Password Incorrect");
    }
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: There's two possible paths to returning 403, do you know which it is? You should be able to narrow this down to client *or* server: is React sending the wrong request, or is the Express app doing the wrong thing for the right request?

Comment: 403 has nothing to do with CORS. That the client sees a 403 suggests that CORS is working just fine.

Comment: I tried the post request from POSTMAN it runs okay, I think there is something regarding the front-end.

Comment: i think in your case req.body is null. when you send request via browser. put a console and check that.  better to use body-parser middleware in express server. it will Parse incoming request bodies. and pass the content-type header  in your api request. 
axios.post(url, data, header);

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the header on the `axios.post` to include the `Content-Type` header.

Example:

```
 axios
      .post("http://localhost:5004/api/auth/login", {
          email:  email ,
          password:  password ,
        }, 
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
)
```

Also, what you may have to do is include the body-parser package on your node api. And get this so that the body can be decoded. However you may not need this. (Your decoded `body` on the node side, could be returning `undefined` for each variable.

Comment: Also, the cors errors wouldn't return a 403, you'd see it as a blocked by cors policy in the browser's network / js console

Comment: Still:
POST http://localhost:5004/api/auth/login 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: What's in your network tab in the browser dev tools?

Comment: is there anything in Response tab?

Comment: Also, is there anything further in their? Would like to see the `Request Headers`

Comment: Here are the request headers, https://prnt.sc/1mv17ly